# Accordion HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css

trying to practice creating an accordion with HTML and CSS.

Code is below along with jsfiddle link.

My question is, when you click on "About", how can I get the "Hoho" to move to the left. I figured that if I add more tabs, their respective content will appear right below them.. how can I get every content that appears to start from the left?

Thanks in advance!

https://jsfiddle.net/g2r7jLe0/

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#link">Home</a>
    <p id="link">Shopify’s Theme Design Team recently released a pretty sweet template for Shopify Merchants called Venture. The layout is optimized for the best shopping experience and provides clear focus on the products. While the layout was developed to accommodate several business cases, for this tutorial example we will focus on the core of the layout and recreate it with flexbox. In the following steps, we’ll learn how to center align elements, set perfect sticky footers, provide priority to certain products dependent on viewport and device, target flexbox elements with media queries, and learn the basics about Flexbox so you can start implementing flexbox layouts in your next web project.Shopify’s Theme Design Team recently released a pretty sweet template for Shopify Merchants called Venture. The layout is optimized for the best shopping experience and provides clear focus on the products. While the layout was developed to accommodate several business cases, for this tutorial example we will focus on the core of the layout and recreate it with flexbox. In the following steps, we’ll learn how to center align elements, set perfect sticky footers, provide priority to certain products dependent on viewport and device, target flexbox elements with media queries, and learn the basics about Flexbox so you can start implementing flexbox layouts in your next web project.
    Shopify’s Theme Design Team recently released a pretty sweet template for Shopify Merchants called Venture. The layout is optimized for the best shopping experience and provides clear focus on the products. While the layout was developed to accommodate several business cases, for this tutorial example we will focus on the core of the layout and recreate it with flexbox. In the following steps, we’ll learn how to center align elements, set perfect sticky footers, provide priority to certain products dependent on viewport and device, target flexbox elements with media queries, and learn the basics about Flexbox so you can start implementing flexbox layouts in your next web project.Shopify’s Theme Design Team recently released a pretty sweet template for Shopify Merchants called Venture. The layout is optimized for the best shopping experience and provides clear focus on the products. While the layout was developed to accommodate several business cases, for this tutorial example we will focus on the core of the layout and recreate it with flexbox. In the following steps, we’ll learn how to center align elements, set perfect sticky footers, provide priority to certain products dependent on viewport and device, target flexbox elements with media queries, and learn the basics about Flexbox so you can start implementing flexbox layouts in your next web project.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#link2">About</a>
    <p id="link2">Hoho</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2s;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

li p:target {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: When you use `#` in front of an `href` value then the Browser moves to the `id` (or `name` attribute in some Browsers). You should use a JavaScript  `onclick` Event and `Element.style.display = 'block';` and `Element.style.display = 'none';` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You did put content in list item(`li`). So your content will start their parents(item) left position.

But, your paragraph element(`p`) has absolute position and you can set absolute left position.

```
p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px; /* set left position to 10px */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2s;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2r7jLe0/1/)**